# How to find where is the warning that eclipse is giving me?

Tags: eclipse

Here is my project structure:

[image]

As you can see, i dont have any warnings on my files, but the project has the warning icon. How do I find where this warning is placed?

Comment: Open the 'Problems' View. Window->Show View->Problems.

Comment: Or use navigator view. If there is problem with some file, other than compilation it would show there.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems like this, I usually bring up the project properties editor, and check things like the build path.  y configuration would produce an error for a build path problem rather than a warning, but maybe you have yours set to warning instead, or you have something similar which would be reported somewhere in the project properties.